# PyAudio cannot find any output devices

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyaudio

When I run:

```
import pyaudio
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
pa.get_default_output_device_info()
```

I get:

```
IOError: No Default Output Device Available
```

When I say:

```
pa.get_device_count()
```

It returns `0L`.

And of course if I list devices

```
for i in range(0, device_count):
        print("Name: " + pa.get_device_info_by_index(i)["name"])
        print("Index: " + pa.get_device_info_by_index(i)["index"])
        print("\n")
```

It will not print anything.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and have set my default sink by going:

```
pacmd list-sinks
pacmd set-default-sink 0
```

I have the latest versions of PulseAudio, ALSA, and PortAudio. Any suggestions?

Update: I also can't view any sound devices on Audacity, despite the fact that they appear under System Settings>Sound. In Audacity I get the error:

> Error while opening sound device. Please check the recording device
>   settings and the project sample rate.

I think that this is almost certainly a PortAudio issue since the settings page looks like:
[image]

Comment: This is probably similar to https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/74?

Comment: Which version of pyaudio are you using?  I'm familiar with the audio system, and can probably help you troubleshoot the source code; but to find the problem, people need to be able to replicate your software setup.

Comment: @NullSalad What speaker do you have?

Comment: @Null Salad.. Offering a bounty a week ago, not answering question that was posted in comments by user2133679, not answering during bounty time if an answer is posted... really, why at all offering a bounty? All to get your "promotor" badge... I guess.....

Comment: lol no, I just forgot about this. I'm using pyaudio 0.2.11, and I have onboard laptop speakers, card: HDA Indetl PCH, Chip Realtek ALC270. Also running python 2.7.12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its likely a broken file that needs replacement.

1. Search for "/usr/./libstdc++.so.6" where pip installed it.
2. Search for "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6" and copy to location at (1). This should fix it.
3. If you have Anaconda version 3 - 4.3.0 or 4.4.0 or earlier installed then check at "anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6" and replance with (2).

Alternatively **A)** rename the file and place the file from (2) where you renamed the old libstdc++.so.6 file or **B)** upgrade to Anaconda to 5.0.1 version and run `conda update --all`. And if you do **"B"** don't forget to remove the eggs or whls manually first to be sure there is no chance installing old software from there again.

This should fix it for you.

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: In step 1, I have lib installed in many locations relative to /usr/ : 

`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
/usr/libx32/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/libx32/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.old

/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22-gdb.py
`
Which should I choose?

Comment: (Sorry for the ugly formatting above, I also had to remove a few under usr/share/.. for space requirements that I considered may have been irrelevant :P)

Comment: Its indeed a lot. However, I use values 1-11 to name each individual path in this stack mentioned. Rename them with "old" when replacing. Replace 1, 5, 7, 10 with 3. and 2, 6, 8, 9 with 4. "11" seems a python file or is that a typo? If that still doesn't work try to replace all accordingly with 1 and 2 or with 5, 6 or 7, 8. Alternatively you can replace them all with just 3 if all previous options don't work.. Time consuming it is this type of debugging ;-(

Comment: OMG. I did this, AND also re-installed portaudio manually (with tarballs, not apt-get) and it WORKS!!!!!!!!! THANK-YOU!

Comment: Although when I run it I get a bunch of errors, I don't know what they mean, but it still works so I'm not complaining:
`ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear 
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe ...
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
... Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
... jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock ...` (shortened to fit)

Comment: Good to hear it now works. U17 is coming... the pre-release is just up on the website. Depending on how much software you've got installed on U16,  I have migrated every now and then to newer U-versions with fresh install, rather than updating from withing a current U-version. This approach requires just one extra HDD or SDD and an extra selection boot-option in the bootloader. This approach makes it less painful "upgrading". its a kind of hard-wired fail-safe. Also, very useful when MS comes with a complete SP (a.k.a ignores the default restore-point software, which imo is for minor changes.)

Comment: Mine is still not OK. I just make installed PortAudio and run the test file 'pa_devs' within its dir. But the output is always "Number of devices = 0". Help!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the package `portaudio19-dev`. Use the following command to install that package using the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```

Answer (score -2):

Install with apt-get; and run with python2. Or install with conda and run with python3.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on your answers , please see this section on how to best put forward your answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer